# Kivy screenshot

Tags: kivy, screenshot

When I make a screenshot in Kivy python, I get numbers at the end of each photo. How can I fix this?
For example, I get "2020-June-books0001.jpg" instead of "2020-June-books.jpg"

```
def screen(self):
    Window.screenshot(f'{self.year_input.text} - {self.month_input.text} - books.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a "feature" of Kivy. You can use [shutil.move()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) to rename it after the fact:

```
def screen(self):
    file_name = Window.screenshot(f'{self.year_input.text} - {self.month_input.text} - books.jpg')
    name_parts = file_name.split('.')
    new_name = ''.join([name_parts[0][:-4], '.', name_parts[1]])
    shutil.move(file_name, new_name)
```

I believe the idea behind the numbering of the screenshot is to avoid overwriting, but this fix will overwrite an older screenshot.